Users service wallet and gas
I have created a service (.NET) that uses Smartcontract.
I chose Infura to work with network infrastructure.
Everything works fine... recently it occurred to me that I need to add something like user wallet management - the reason is... users need to have "cash" for gas and I don't want the user to have to deal with the wallet and ETH.
What is the most efficient way of dealing with this issue?
Should I use Ethereum network or is there any other network that is trustworthy? Or maybe I should create my own network or something like this?
Any hint is appreciated.

I think Relayers can be a good solution to your problem . A relayer service can submit transactions on behalf of users and pay the gas fees, while users pay you in a different way (e.g., through a subscription or a percentage of their transactions). You should be able to implement a relayer service on top of Ethereum chain. If you dont want to implement directly on the ethereum mainnet , you can implent you relayer service on layer 2 solutions also .

Thanks for this, will check it

@michal If you found it useful, could you mark it as an answer mate :)
